# Center text vertically along a floating "shape-outside" polygon elements path

Tags: css

I want to use a shape to control the flow of text. So I've added a floating div (`.cutout`) with a shape-outside and clip-path defined. The neighboring div's inline content line breaks along this path as expected (`.innertext`).

The problem is I want that text to be centered vertically along side this path. I've tried positioning tricks and margin tricks but these break the flow of the inline elements along the polygons path.

Is there any way to vertically align a group of inline elements within the height of the `cutout`'s parent container while keeping the `innertext` element's ability to line break respective to the `shape-outside` polygon path?

```css
html,body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.cutout {
  float: right;
  background-color: #faa;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  shape-outside: polygon(0 100%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%);
}

.innertext {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="cutout">
  </div>
  
  <div class="innertext">
    <h1>
      Lorem Ipsum
    </h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.  
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you may need Javascript for this - is that acceptable?

Comment: @fordat it's vertical centering that is required, not horizontal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flexbox: center horizontally and vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026884/flexbox-center-horizontally-and-vertically)

Comment: I'm trying it out and it seems that any attempt at centering the element requires a display type that prevents it from flowing how the OP wants ... looks like it needs to stay as `display: block`. Not sure this can be done without Javascript but I'm trying lol

Comment: I am sorry this question has been closed as it seems to me that it is clear. The only non-clear aspect is whether JS is acceptable to the OP. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @AHaworth i've edited for clarity and hope this reopens. I'm still trying to find a solution in CSS ... it's a great question. If the OP chimes in and requests a solution in Javascript I'm sure we can solve it for them rather quickly

Comment: @SpencerMay I have a nasty feeling this isn't CSS-only soluble. Christoffer, can you say whether a Javascript solution would be OK?

Comment: @AHaworth I was mainly looking for a css/html-solution since my current "solution" is to offset the text with a padding-top, and I guess I could do that dynamically with javascript to adapt to different texts. But I was hoping there would be a way to solve this without javascript, but perhaps there isn't?

Comment: Now that I come to think of it, a  javascript solution might also be quite interesting. Naively I tried to use the difference in height between the innertext-block and its parent and set padding-top to half that. But given that the shape is slanting that doesn't really center the text vertically anyway. And that approach would certainly not work with more oddly shaped outlines. With that said, I'm primarliy looking for a css/html solution if that is possible.

Comment: @AHaworth i think you're right. I was so close with using another shape as a mask but i couldn't scale it properly with calc not accepting vh and vw in one equation. This whole situation makes me want to rewrite css 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid I can't find a CSS/HTML only solution that would fit any shape.

So this snippet takes a simplistic approach - keeps moving the text down until the space below and above can be made equal with padding.

This ensures that any adjustment in height of the text element due to wrapping around the shape are taken into account.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const innerText = document.querySelector('.innertext');
const containerStyle = getComputedStyle(container);
const innerTextStyle = getComputedStyle(innerText);

function reposition() {
  const height = Number(containerStyle.height.slice(0, -2));
  let innerHeight = Number(innerTextStyle.height.slice(0, -2));
  let paddingTop = 0;
  while (((paddingTop * 2) + innerHeight) < height) {
    paddingTop++;
    innerText.style.paddingTop = paddingTop + 'px';
    innerHeight = Number(getComputedStyle(innerText).height.slice(0, -2));
  }
  innerText.style.paddingTop = (paddingTop - 1) + 'px';
}
window.onresize = reposition;
reposition();
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.innerText :first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.cutout {
  float: right;
  background-color: #faa;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  shape-outside: polygon(0 100%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="cutout">
  </div>

  <div class="innertext">
    <h1>
      Lorem Ipsum
    </h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the javascript answer, I must say it's pretty insane if you have to do it this way, but hey, it does work! :) I'll leave it unanswered for avwhile in hope that someone can find a way to do this with html/css, since this feels more like a workaround than a solution to be honest.

Comment: Well, it's a workaround that does work, but in my opinion is a bit scruffy. Let's hope for a CSS solution, tho' finding one for a random shape seems unlikely.